# Maintain multiple row data in single row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

> There is my table look like

| id | name | deduction | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | teat | Home Rent | 1000 |
| 01 | test | GPF | 500 |

> i want show my data in deduction report like below table

| id | name | home_rent | gpf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | teat | 1000 | 500 |

> mysql code

```
  SELECT a.* , a.amount as home_rent ,b.amount as gpf FROM my_table as a ,my_table as b where a.deduction = Home Rent and b.deduction = GPF
```

> what i have done wrong please let me know ? what can i do for my report to it look like my second table thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

We can use conditional aggregation and pivoting here:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN deduction = 'Home Rent' THEN amount END) AS home_rent,
    MAX(CASE WHEN deduction = 'GPF'       THEN amount END) AS gpf
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(4),
  `deduction` VARCHAR(9),
  `amount` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`id`, `name`, `deduction`, `amount`)
VALUES
  ('01', 'test', 'Home Rent', 1000),
  ('01', 'test', 'GPF', 500);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN deduction = 'Home Rent' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS home_rent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN deduction = 'GPF' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS gpt    
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

| id | name | home_rent | gpt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 1000 | 500 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)